# .NET RIA Services and Inheritance in EF

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

How i can use Inheritance in Entity Framework with .NET RIA Services?
Problem:
if there is inheritance in EF, silverlight application don't compiled.
Can you help me?

Comment: No, I can't help you. Not unless you show the actual compiler error.

Comment: the fact that RIA can't generate inheritance in client code.
I am looking for people who work with RIA and solve such a problem.

Comment: I disagree with the "fact." But unless you're willing to show what you're actually trying to do and what the compiler error is, I can't help.

Comment: I have the next propblem http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/96478/260330.aspx and I am looking solution of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> Type 'Common.Individual' is a direct or indirect subclass of Type 'Common.Customer'. DomainServices cannot return a Type that is a subclass of another Type returned from the same DomainService.

...does not mean "no inheritance support." It *does* mean that (in the current version of RIA services) you can't return both a parent and a child type to the client.

That is a limitation, and it's a limitation you have to live with in RIA Services for now. That said, I don't think it's as big as a limitation as the thread you reference implies. Is not the same as saying you cannot use inheritance at all. Also, I think that inheritance tends to be overused in entity mapping for reasons I explain in great detail in [this presentation](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/04/38373/).

So while I can't fix the limitation, my suggestions are:

- Use composition instead of inheritance when appropriate (cf. the presentation referenced above).
- When you must use inheritance, RIA Services will require that you don't return the parent type.